# Change UITableView section header when it's on top

Tags: swift, uitableview, header

I am using a custom header from Xib file for my table view using this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let result: Result = (self.responseData?.result![section])!

    let headerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderViewTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as!  HeaderViewTableViewCell
   headerCell.sectionName.text = "Title"
    if (section == 0) {
        headerCell.sectionName.textColor = UIColor(red: 49/255.0, green: 149/255.0, blue: 213/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }

    return headerCell
}
```

Then I want to change the header sectionName when it is scrolled to top, I have tried this code

```
let topSection = self.mainTable .indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.section
let currentHeader : HeaderViewTableViewCell = self.mainTable .headerView(forSection: topSection!) as HeaderViewTableViewCell
currentHeader.sectionName.textColor = UIColor.red
```

But I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to type 'HeaderViewTableViewCell' in coercion
Is there any way to cast the headerView to my custom type?

Comment: show HeaderViewTableViewCell's code

Comment: @vikingosegundo It's a UITableViewCell class which includes outlets and awakeFromNib

Comment: why would you use a UITableViewCell as header?

Comment: @vikingosegundo I want to use a custom view

Comment: Isn't your section header 0 always on top anyway?

Comment: @AuRis No I have 4 sections and when I scroll and all section 0's cells are not visible section 1 is going to stick to top, It's UITableView regular action

Comment: And what do you want to do with your section 0 when it scrolls away? I am not understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Or do you want to change the title of all sections when they stick to top?

Comment: @AuRis I want to highlight the header for the section which is on top and make other sections gray

Comment: you should subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView, not UITableViewCell.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thanks! But it doesnt include XIB file! How can I create view?

Comment: @Niloufar please check my answer.

Comment: You *subclass* it. so you can create your xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for your header view. You can make a subclass and add custom code. For this example I will use an empty subclass:

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        // set you default color (other properties) here.
        // when scrolling fast the view gets reused and sometimes
        // the view that's on top will suddenly appear on the bottom still with the previous values
        textLabel?.textColor = .black
    }
}
```

Register your header view (I am skipping all other unrelated code):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(HeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")

    // If you have a nib file for your HeaderView then register nib instead
    // Make sure in our nib file you set class name to HeaderView
    // And the file name is also HeaderView.xib
    // tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil) , forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")

}
```

Implement delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header")
    view?.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    return view
}
```

Create a method for updating headers:

```
// Iterates through section header views and 
// checks for positions in relation to the tableview offset
func updateHeaders() {
    var sectionHeaders: [Int: HeaderView?] = [:]

    var i = 0
    while i < numberOfSections {
        sectionHeaders[i] = tableView.headerView(forSection: i) as? HeaderView
        i += 1
    }

    let availableHeaders = sectionHeaders.flatMap { $0.value != nil ? $0 : nil }
    for (index, header) in availableHeaders {
        let rect = tableView.rectForHeader(inSection: index)

        if rect.origin.y <=  tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.contentInset.top || index == 0 {
            header!.textLabel?.textColor = .red
        } else {
            header!.textLabel?.textColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

And call your `updateHeaders()` from UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateHeaders()
}
```

Also update headers before the view will be displayed (before any scroll appeared), for that use the UITableViewDelegate method `willDisplayHeaderView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    updateHeaders()
}
```

Comment: Thanks but UITableViewHeaderFooterView class doesn't include XIB file which I want it to design my custom header view

Comment: I have a custom header which includes an icon and 2 label

Comment: Thanks but in update header I want the header to cast to HeaderView type but it crashes:
            let header: HeaderView = self.mainTable.headerView(forSection: i) as! HeaderView

Comment: It may happen that `scrollViewDidScroll` gets called before any headers are created, in that case it will crash. I edited the answer to check for headers optionally.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I still have problems which sometimes two of them are red \

Comment: My bad. I did not account for the fact that `return` will escape the `while` loop and will not update the rest of the views. I edited the answer in a way that only the available views are updated.